# How to convert pandas data frame to NumPy array?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

Following the suggestions I got from my previous [question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61208808/how-to-use-pandas-dataframes-with-sklearn) I'm converting a Pandas data frame to a numeric NumPy array. To do this Im used `numpy.asarray`.

My data frame:

```
DataFrame
----------
       label                                             vector
0         0   1:0.0033524514 2:-0.021896651 3:0.05087798 4:...
1         0   1:0.02134219 2:-0.007388343 3:0.06835007 4:0....
2         0   1:0.030515702 2:-0.0037591448 3:0.066626 4:0....
3         0   1:0.0069114454 2:-0.0149497045 3:0.020777626 ...
4         1   1:0.003118149 2:-0.015105667 3:0.040879637 4:...
...     ...                                                ...
19779     0   1:0.0042634667 2:-0.0044222944 3:-0.012995412...
19780     1   1:0.013818732 2:-0.010984628 3:0.060777966 4:...
19781     0   1:0.00019213723 2:-0.010443398 3:0.01679976 4...
19782     0   1:0.010373874 2:0.0043582567 3:-0.0078354385 ...
19783     1   1:0.0016790542 2:-0.028346825 3:0.03908631 4:...

[19784 rows x 2 columns]

DataFrame datatypes :
 label     object
vector    object
dtype: object
```

To convert into a Numpy Array I'm using this script:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn import svm
from sklearn import metrics
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

r_filenameTSV = 'TSV/A19784.tsv'

tsv_read = pd.read_csv(r_filenameTSV, sep='\t',names=["vector"])

df = pd.DataFrame(tsv_read)

df = pd.DataFrame(df.vector.str.split(' ',1).tolist(),
                                   columns = ['label','vector'])


print('DataFrame\n----------\n', df)
print('\nDataFrame datatypes :\n', df.dtypes)

arr = np.asarray(df, dtype=np.float64)

print('\nNumpy Array\n----------\n', arr)
print('\nNumpy Array Datatype :', arr.dtype)
```

I'm having this error from line nr.22 `arr = np.asarray(df, dtype=np.float64)`

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: ' 1:0.0033524514 2:-0.021896651 3:0.05087798 4:0.0072637126 5:-0.013740167 6:-0.0014883851 7:0.02230502 8:0.0053563705 9:0.00465044 10:-0.0030826542 11:0.010156203 12:-0.021754289 13:-0.03744049 14:0.011198468 15:-0.021201309 16:-0.0006497681 17:0.009229079 18:0.04218278 19:0.020572046 20:0.0021593391 ...
```

How can I solve this issue?

Regards and thanks for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use list comprehension with nested dictionary comprehension for `DataFrame`:

```
df = pd.read_csv(r_filenameTSV, sep='\t',names=["vector"])

df = pd.DataFrame([dict(y.split(':') for y in x.split()) for x in df['vector']])
print (df)
              1              2            3    4
0  0.0033524514   -0.021896651   0.05087798    0
1    0.02134219   -0.007388343   0.06835007    0
2   0.030515702  -0.0037591448     0.066626    0
3  0.0069114454  -0.0149497045  0.020777626    0
4   0.003118149   -0.015105667  0.040879637  0.4
```

And then convert to floats and to numpy array:

```
print (df.astype(float).to_numpy())
[[ 0.00335245 -0.02189665  0.05087798  0.        ]
 [ 0.02134219 -0.00738834  0.06835007  0.        ]
 [ 0.0305157  -0.00375914  0.066626    0.        ]
 [ 0.00691145 -0.0149497   0.02077763  0.        ]
 [ 0.00311815 -0.01510567  0.04087964  0.4       ]]
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems one of your columns is a string, not an integer. Either remove that column or encode it as a string before converting the dataframe to an array